# how to replace a fragment within a ListViewPagerAdapter.java

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using ViewPager in a fragment. It has 3 tabs

Here's the code of my fragmentOagerAdapter:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassA.class.getName());
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassB.class.getName());
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassC.class.getName());
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
    String res = "";
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            res = "nameA";
            break;
        case 1:
            res = "nameB";
            break;
        case 2:
            res = "nameC";
            break;
    }
    return res;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

I'm adding a a button in my main fragment that will allow me to switch between a list display and a grid display.
So what I want is to have a dynamic fragment depending on some enum stored within the Preferences
I want to do this for the 1st tab (position 0)

So I do the following:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            switch (Settings.getInstance().getProductDisplayMode()) {
                case LARGE_GRID:
                    fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassALargeGrid.class.getName());
                    break;
                case SMALL_GRID:
                    fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassASmallGrid.class.getName());
                    break;
                case LIST:
                default:
                    fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassA.class.getName());
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassB.class.getName());
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.context, ClassC.class.getName());
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

...
```

So it works fine when first opening the activity, but I don't know how to switch the fragment displayed in the first tab dynamically.

I tried calling destroyItem() on the FragmentPagerAdapter but it doesn't help...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem a while back. I wound up having to  take the fragment out of the viewpager and then use the `FragmentManager` to swap out the fragments dynamically.

Then, when I wanted to switch to another "page," I wrote some custom animations to "slide in" a fragment that hosted a `ViewPager`

Not a pretty solution, but it worked.

Comment: I'm already in the correct tab, so calling setCurrentItem(0) won't help me. What I'm asking is how can I replace the fragment already created within the 1st tab by a new one

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry I misunderstood. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Another solution would be to trigger the fragment re creation, and to select the correct layout/adapter in the fragment onCreateView/OnViewCreated method... but still how to force the fragment to be recreated ?